# Authentication object is null after bypassing the particular request

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, jwt, spring-security-rest

The below Code I used in webConfigSecurity class to bypass some requests from the client

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception
{
    webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers("/adminSettings/get/**")
             .antMatchers("/cases/sayHello/**").antMatchers("/cases/**/downloadPdfFolderPBC/**");
}
```

In the controller api method requires the user details for further execution, while getting the user details the authentication object is null, so it throws an exception that "user is not authenticated"

```
 public static User get() {
        final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication != null) {
            UserPrincipal principal = (UserPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal();
            if (principal == null) {
                throw new InsufficientAuthenticationException("User not authenticated");
            }
            return principal.getUser();
        }
        throw new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException("User not authenticated");
    }
```

I'm new to spring security, In this case, what I should do to get logged user details

Comment: How is the request getting authenticated? Spring Security is essentially a set of request filters that intercept and authenticate credentials - if you are not supplying credentials in the request, there's nothing for Spring Security to authenticate.

Comment: using the json webtokens for authenticating each request. In my case i have bypassed that request. After bypassing authentication is null.

Comment: If you've bypassed Spring Security for a given request, then there's nothing setting the `SecurityContextHolder`. `ignoring()` means "Spring Security shouldn't do anything with this request".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ignoring()`, which causes Spring Security to skip those requests, I believe you want to use `permitAll()` instead like so:

```java
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests((requests) -> requests
            .antMatcher("/adminSettings/get/**").permitAll()
            .antMatcher("/cases/sayHello/**").permitAll()
            // ... etc
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());
}
```

In this way, Spring Security will still populate the `SecurityContextHolder` with the logged-in user, but none of the `permitAll` endpoints will require authentication.